# Check the result of Windows User Access Control (UAC) for a running subprocess from C++

Tags: c++, windows, uac

Good afternoon.
I have a C++ program that, at some point, launches another program (more precisely, an installer for another program). This launches the Windows User Access Control (UAC) dialog. How can I understand from the first program that the user has declined the launch of the second program in the UAC dialog (and how can I understand that the user has confirmed the launch)?

Didn't find any answers on how to check this.

Comment: You need to inspect results of launcher function such as `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess

Comment: (Correction: UAC is User _Account_ Control, not User _Access_ Control)